# Compiling PrimeFaces 1.1

Tags: java, maven, compilation, primefaces

I am trying to modify the PrimeFaces 1.1 sources to fit my application needs. However I ran into trouble compiling the sources.

I am using the sources from:

http://repository.prime.com.tr/org/primefaces/primefaces/1.1/

Downloaded and extracted:

primefaces-1.1-sources.jar

However when i try to run the primefaces-1.1.pom it fails because its referencing to some XML files which contains the tag info, but I couldn't find those in the sources. I assume this build file is for PrimeFaces 2.x?

Or am i missing something? Would be great if you could help me!

**Using Maven "Install"**

```
"c:\program files (x86)\jetbrains\intellij idea 10.0\jre\jre\bin\java" -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\Werk\Binaries\Maven\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=D:\Werk\Binaries\Maven -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "D:\Werk\Binaries\Maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --no-plugin-updates --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\primefaces-1.1-sources\pom.xml install
[WARNING] Command line option -npu is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
[WARNING] Command line option -npr is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:1.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 156, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building primefaces 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- xslt-maven-plugin:1.0:transform (generate-ui-metadata) @ primefaces ---
[ERROR] XSL file does not exist: C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\primefaces-1.1-sources\src\main\resources-maven-jsf\misc\resolve_entities.xsl
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- xslt-maven-plugin:1.0:transform (generate-touch-metadata) @ primefaces ---
[ERROR] XSL file does not exist: C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\primefaces-1.1-sources\src\main\resources-maven-jsf\misc\resolve_entities.xsl
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jsf-plugin:1.1.3:generate-tld (generate-ui) @ primefaces ---
[INFO] Generating TLD
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.711s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 30 11:29:43 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.primefaces:maven-jsf-plugin:1.1.3:generate-tld (generate-ui) on project primefaces: Execution generate-ui of goal org.primefaces:maven-jsf-plugin:1.1.3:generate-tld failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to modify a single class (or a few), it may be easiest to take that class's source code alone, modify and compile it with the rest of Primefaces as JAR in the classpath, then replace that single class file in the JAR.